# Increment a counter in a sql select query and sum by value?

Tags: pervasive-sql

I'm trying to do something a little different in a Pervasive DB.

I have a query result that comes out a little like this

```
part#     Qty  
----------------
A123       10
A123        3
B234       13
B234       43
A123       24
```

I can sort them with no problem. What I need is to iterate over the unique values and get a total count of them so I get something like this:

```
part#     Qty    Num    OfNum
-----------------------------
A123       10     1       3
A123       3      2       3
B234       13     1       2
B234       43     2       2
A123       24     3       3
```

I am stuck on how to this in Pervasive.

Comment: Youve tagged this with 2 different RDBMS - which are you really using?

Comment: What are you expecting for an answer here? You said you "might" be able to figure it out in sql server but not in another DBMS.

Comment: I said in the beginning I am trying to do this in Pervasive.  I can remove the sql-server tag id need be, but SQL engine is different than pervasive.  So even if I could figure it out in SQL, I don't know how to do it in Pervasive (hence the question)

Comment: Perhaps an understanding of the goal would help.  At first glance, this seems like a very odd bit of information to want about these records, as part of the overall result set as you've shown it.

Comment: Sorry, I realized the results wanted were unclear.  I need to get an incremented number for each part that goes up to the total (ofNum). So it would be something like 1 of 3, 2 of 3, 3 of 3, 1 of 2, 2 of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you:

```
SELECT t1.PartNumber, t1.Qty, (SELECT COUNT(PartNumber) FROM "myTable" WHERE PartNumber = t1.PartNumber) AS "OfNum"
FROM "myTable" AS t1
```

...replacing names as appropriate, of course.